# Update partial view using Ajax not working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Experimenting with partial views in MVC 5, can't refresh my partial view using Ajax on button click:

This is my partial view:

```
@model dbsapplication.Models.CarRepository

   @{
        Layout = null;
   }

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Engine)
```

in my Index page, I have:

```
<div id="@car.ID">
       @Html.Partial("PartialView", car)
</div>
```

and my button:

```
<button onclick="loadProject(@car.ID)">Car ID: @car.ID</button>
```

My Ajax call:

```
<script>
function loadProject(car_ID) {
//alert('#' + car_ID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/partialView/',
        data: { id: car_ID },            
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#' + car_ID).empty();
            $('#' + car_ID).html(data);
            alert("Updated!");
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

my controller:

```
public PartialViewResult partialView(int id)
{
   CarRepository car = new CarRepository();
   car.updateCar_partial(id);
   return PartialView("PartialView", car);
}
```

car.updateCar_partial(id);

This method simply sets the Engine for a given car back to default value which is ("Not specififed"). When I click the button, the ajax call runs and the alert is triggered but the DIV the data is meant to load into goes blank. Only when I refresh the page, the partial view is updated to the correct value.

Refreshed via F5 or when I add location.reload which i think defeats the purpose as this reloads the whole page not the div.

Not sure if what i'm doing is possible, any help would be appreciated.

Other question I have to try and fix:

[Update Partial View Within Partial View Using MVC Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511138/update-partial-view-within-partial-view-using-mvc-ajax) 
[AJAX not updating partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151070/ajax-not-updating-partial-view)

Comment: what you get in data ?? - The ID of the car selected. I used alert to output the car ID and it outputs correct data

Comment: When you load the view for the first time `@car.Id` has any value? Did you observe the HTML and see if id for div is set properly?

Comment: i think in MVC 5 you can not access to a  partial view. test get a view have partial view

Comment: Dude just debug on the line "return PartialView("PartialView", car);". Can you see object car is having the data you want ?

Comment: Yes - when i 'view page source', @car.Id has the correct values

Comment: You don't need the `.empty()` call as you're replacing via `.html()`

Comment: In the `success:` add `console.dir(data)`

Comment: To answer your query if this is possible: what you're doing (attempting to do) is exactly what PartialViews are for.

Comment: @rem you can use jquery load() function to achieve your goal with much less code

Comment: This is what i get exactly when observing the console via Chrome: http://localhost:65327/Home/partialView/?id=3&_=1499252266753. I've added a breakpoint in my controller anyway to see if the ID is passed and it is

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the javascript/jquery/controller/action.  The only part we can't see is `car.updateCar_partial(id);`.  Given how most repositories work, you *possibly* want this line to be `car = car.updateCar_partial(id);`

Comment: The issue isn't jquery->controller, it's what's being rendered in the partial view before it's passed back to the jquery.  ie this part `return PartialView("PartialView", car);`  if `car.Engine` is not set correctly at this point (regardless of what it has done in the DB) then the partial will render correctly, but the data provided is not correct.

Comment: I think you are right, as matter of fact when setting a break point on return PartialView("PartialView", car); for the object car: all the model values (name, type, engine) are null expect the ID, then when the partial is being updated, the engine is null and when i manually refresh the index page, it retrieves everything back and the new value appears. To fix this, would I need to instead of passing just the ID but pass the car object and then update the engine? is this possible via this method?

Comment: I added the car object to the public PartialViewResult partialView(CarRepository car, int id) and that is also null, so i think this is the problem

Comment: No - only pass the `id` to the action.  The issue is to do with what you do in the MVC action, not how you pass that back/forth to the client/front-end.   Your repository model `CarRepository` is currently broken / not doing what you think it should.   Before the `return PartialView(` add: `car.Engine = "test engine";`.  You should then get this in the front end when you click the button.   You need to setup the `car` properties in the action.

Comment: Yeah I did that - it worked. Changed the engine to "test engine". Regards to your solution.You need to setup the car properties in the action - would I need to repopulate the car object with the new values? not sure what the approach to fixing this would be

Comment: It's *possible* you're misunderstanding how MVC works - think of each request to your MVC application as a whole new program.  The repository is recreated each time, the car object is new on each request, etc.  (I apologise, I forget the exact term for this in MVC terminology).  In your partial action, you need to load the car object from the DB, set its values as desired, save back to the DB then return the model that you loaded to the partial.

Comment: It worked! I did the following: get the car based on ID, do the operation required (in this instance, update engine) then get the car based on ID again to get the updated values and pass this car object to the partial view

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use jquery `load()` function to fill partial view into your target html element like following.

```
function loadProject(car_ID) {

     var url = '@Url.Action("partialView", "Home")' + "?id=" + car_ID;
     var targetElement = $("#" + car_ID);

     targetElement.load(url, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
         if(statusTxt == "success")
         console.log("It worked");
     })
}
```

Comment: @freedomn-m OP can use load callback function to check "responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr" parameters to check if there is error in ajax request

Comment: Updated comment to remove the bit that's confusing you:  While a fine suggestion, **this will still have the same problem** as $.load() is *just a shortcut for the code in the question*.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for information :), I assumed that Partial action and its view work successfully so it was a suggestion to make ajax call with much less code